# Issues while compiling a Go app from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, go, debian

My issue:

I need to compile a Go application from Windows (current workspace) to Linux (deployment environment), I've try several times using few techniques described in this platform and many more and nothing help, everything looks fine but isn't work.

I'm compiling for linux using this script in windows

```
$ set GOARCH=amd64
$ set GOOS=linux
$ go build app_name.go
```

in the `cmd` folder I can find a file named `app_name` with no extension, which should be fine.
Then, I receive an error when trying to execute the binary in Linux, using few ways

```
$ ./app_name
-bash: ./app_name: Permission denied

$ source app_name
-bash: source: app_name: cannot execute binary file
```

this is the file that I received after the compilation:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx  xxx  7313830 Jan 26 16:59 app_name
```

If I run the application in windows with `go run -arguments app_name.go` it works perfect, but the issue appear after compile or try to compile the app for linux, I can't run the app even as `root`

Comment: So what exactly is the correlation between `unified_mapper` and `app_name`?

Comment: P.S.: What's with the `$` in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix systems, a file must have the executable bit set in order to be able to be run.  This is the only way that the system knows what programs or scripts can be run, and differs from Windows, which uses extensions.

In this case, you need to change permissions by running `chmod u+x unified_mapper` before trying to execute it.  If you want other users to execute it as well, you can do something like `chmod 755 unified_mapper`.  Run `man 1 chmod` in the manual page to see more details about possible invocations.